# Scrollable Pane does not show contents

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I cannot find out why this will not show the contents:

```
public class Bans implements ActionListener {

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    draw();
}

public static JFrame frame;

public static void draw() {
    frame = new JFrame("Ban History");
    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(575,250));

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    JLabel label = new JLabel("Ban History");
    label.setFont(Main.header);
    label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);


    JPanel container = new JPanel();
    JPanel border = new JPanel();
    JScrollPane scrPane = new JScrollPane(border);
    border.add(container);

    container.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));
    scrPane.setBorder(null);

    for(Ban ban : Main.banlist) {
        System.out.println(ban.id);
        JPanel whitespace = new JPanel();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.getHSBColor(176F, 25.46F, 65.12F));
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(510,0));
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,2));


        JLabel banDate = new JLabel();
        banDate.setText("(#" + ban.id + ")  Ban Date:  " + ban.banDate.toString() + "        ");
        banDate.setFont(Main.body);
        panel.add(banDate);

        JLabel banName = new JLabel();
        banName.setText("Banned By:  " + ban.bannedByName);
        banName.setFont(Main.body);
        panel.add(banName);

        JLabel banReason = new JLabel();
        banReason.setText("Reason: " + ban.banReason);
        banReason.setFont(Main.body);
        panel.add(banReason);

        JLabel banTime = new JLabel();
        banTime.setText("Ban Time: " + ban.banTime);
        banTime.setFont(Main.body);
        banTime.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        panel.add(banTime);

        container.add(whitespace);
        whitespace.add(panel);
    }


    frame.add(label,BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    frame.add(scrPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

}
```

It was working earlier, however now none of the contents of the ScrollPane show. I'm fairly new with Swing, however I would think that this should work. Yes, there are contents in the table. When ran it does print out 5 id numbers, which correspond to the correct numbers on the MySQL server, so that should be working fine.

Comment: What is `Main`? We don't have that code

Comment: It holds all of the main things including the fonts and lists... banlist is literally just List<Ban>, and the others are formats. That code is not super useful, and should not affect this problem.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] that we can copy-paste and see your issue, that way we don't have to try to fix it to compile and then try to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Why do you create panels called "border" and "container"? Why not just add container to the scrollpane and eliminate border? Same thing for "whitespace" - it just contains "panel" - you can eliminate whitespace.

Comment: If I don't add the whitespace it'll take up the whole portion of that area, preferred size doesn't seem to matter.

Comment: It is additionally not possible to post a complete example because it uses a MySQL server to get that data

Comment: Post hardcoded data then instead of one that comes from the database

Answer (score 1):

The content is being added, but isn't being displayed because of how you have designed your layout, as the panels representing your bans have no height:

`panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(510,0));`

By following [@FredK's suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37950260/scrollable-pane-does-not-show-contents#comment63350243_37950260)  in the comments, you can maintain the effect of your `whitespace` panel by applying a vertical gap between the rows in your layout. This is provided by another constructor available within [`GridLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html): `GridLayout(int rows, int cols, int hgap, int vgap)`

There are some demos available here: [How to Use GridLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html)

---

By mocking up some bans, I got the following with your code:

[image: bans]

Note: By applying the suggestions (with a vgap of 5) the output was the same as the above

---

**Side note:** If you find something was working earlier it tends to be from a change you've made. If you use IntelliJ as your IDE there is a helpful feature for this called a **Local History**. By right clicking on the class you can see line-by-line comparisons of changes you made to the class with time stamps, similar to source control. You can read more here: [Using Local History](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/using-local-history.html)

I'm not saying you have to change your IDE, but as a beginner if you are doing a lot of experimentation you may find some benefit in it